# Moveit with multiple rviz

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using moveit trying to robot arm, For some purpose,  I need to connect two rviz to the same master.

When I operate in one rviz window, two rviz simulation robot will move.

Is there anyway I can only let the rviz window I operate move, the another rviz will not move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226849/moveit-with-multiple-rviz/) by [chenchengshao@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/25677/chenchengshao@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is not a simulator but a visulizer, which means that you're viewing the same robot. As such they are expected to show the same movements.

If you want independent behavior you will need to launch two versions of the robot arm and connect one rviz to each.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0